# Factors ordered vs. levels

Tags: r

Can someone explain what is the use of the "ordered" parameter in R?

R says:

> ordered
>   logical flag to determine if the levels should be regarded as ordered (in the order given).

So if I have a factor called names and set ordered = TRUE

```
names<- factor(c("fred","bob","john"), ordered = TRUE)
names
```

Why does it print out:

```
[1] fred bob  john
Levels: bob < fred < john
```

which seems like it did not use the order I gave it. I started with fred it starts with Bob?

Also how is the ordered parameter used differently from using the "levels" parameters which will order the factors:

```
names<- factor(c("fred","bob","john"), levels= c("john","fred","bob"))
names
```

This returns

```
[1] fred bob  john
Levels: john fred bob
```

Which seems like it is following my ordering.  So why do I need the "ordered" parameter?

I am confused as to how "ordered" and "levels" are used.

Comment: The first part of your question is answered simply by reading the documentation, in particular the section on the `levels` argument.

Comment: this is far from obvious, but the only (?) major difference between a factor and an unordered factor in R is the default contrast used in linear (generalized linear etc.) models -- default for regular (unordered) factors is treatment (`?contr.treatment`), default for ordered factors is polynomial (`?contr.poly`) -- see `options("contrasts")`.  The other difference is that you can use inequality operators (`<`, `>` etc.) to compare levels of ordered factors.

Answer (score 12):

I'll replace your vector of names by more intuitive factors for which order makes more sense:

```
heights <- c("low","medium","high")

heights1 <- factor(heights, ordered = TRUE)
heights1
# [1] low    medium high  
# Levels: high < low < medium

heights2 <- factor(heights) # ordered = FALSE by default
heights2
# [1] low    medium high  
# Levels: high low medium
```

The order of the levels might not be the one you expect, but when you don't set an explicit order levels are sorted **alphabetically**.

To set an **explicit order** we can do as follows:

```
heights1<- factor(heights, levels = heights, ordered = TRUE)
heights1
# [1] low    medium high  
# Levels: low < medium < high

heights2<- factor(heights, levels = heights)
heights2
# [1] low    medium high  
# Levels: low medium high
```

You might sometimes want to use `factor(x, levels = unique(x))` as levels can't be duplicated, in this case levels will be sorted by their first appearance.

So now it's sorted on both sides, but wait, one is supposed to be "unordered".
The vocabulary is misleading as sorting unordered factors is possible, and even useful if you want to tweak your layouts with `ggplot2` for instance.

However, as mentioned by @joran and @thomas, statistical models will consider categorical variables differently depending on whether they are ordered or not.

The use of ordered factors that led me here however is in the use of `max` and `min` functions, in particular inside of aggregation functions.

See this question and the accepted answer where having factors defined as ordered is necessary : [Aggregate with max and factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196033/aggregate-with-max-and-factors)

We had this:

```
# > df1
#    id height
# 1   1    low          
# 2   1   high         
# 3   2 medium          
# 4   2    low          
# 5   3 medium          
# 6   3 medium          
# 7   4    low          
# 8   4    low          
# 9   5 medium          
# 10  5 medium
```

With unordered factors we couldn't aggregate:

```
# aggregate(height ~ id,df1,max)
# Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
# ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
```

With ordered factors we can!

```
# aggregate(height ~ id,df1,max)
#   id height
# 1  1   high
# 2  2 medium
# 3  3 medium
# 4  4    low
# 5  5 medium
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's do some reading.

From `?factor`:

> **levels**     an optional vector of the values that x might have taken. The
>   default is the unique set of values taken by as.character(x), sorted
>   into increasing order of x. Note that this set can be specified as
>   smaller than sort(unique(x)).

So if left unspecified, it will sort the unique values for you and treat that as the order.

As Ben mentioned, the question of how ordered and unordered factors differ in practice is much more complicated and usually relies on a presumption that you know a reasonable amount of statistics. The documentation only says:

> Ordered factors differ from factors only in their class, but methods
>   and the model-fitting functions treat the two classes quite
>   differently.

Again, as Ben mentions, many model fitting routines will treat ordered and unordered factors very differently because they have very different statistical meanings and interpretations. A detailed summary of the statistical differences is probably way beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.