# Sorting one variable in a data frame by id

Tags: r, sorting, grouping

I have a data frame with lot of company information separated by an id variable. I want to sort one of the variables and repeat it for every id. Let's take this example,

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(110, 110, 110, 90, 90, 90, 90, 252, 252
), var1 = c(26, 21, 54, 10, 18, 9, 16, 54, 39), var2 = c(234, 
12, 43, 32, 21, 19, 16, 34, 44)), .Names = c("id", "var1", "var2"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like this

```
df
   id var1 var2
1 110   26  234
2 110   21   12
3 110   54   43
4  90   10   32
5  90   18   21
6  90    9   19
7  90   16   16
8 252   54   34
9 252   39   44
```

Now, I want to sort the data frame according to `var1` by the vector `id`. Easiest solution I can think of is using `apply` function like this,

```
> apply(df, 2, sort)
       id var1 var2
 [1,]  90    9   12
 [2,]  90   10   16
 [3,]  90   16   19
 [4,]  90   18   21
 [5,] 110   21   32
 [6,] 110   26   34
 [7,] 110   39   43
 [8,] 252   54   44
 [9,] 252   54  234
```

However, this is not the output I am seeking. The correct output should be,

```
   id var1 var2
1 110   21   12
2 110   26  234
3 110   54   43
4  90    9   19
5  90   10   32
6  90   16   16
7  90   18   21
8 252   39   44
9 252   54   34
```

Group by `id` and sort by `var1` column **and** keep original `id` column order.

Any idea how to sort like this?

Comment: Isn't this just `df %>%  arrange(id, var1)`  in `dplyr` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: I don't believe this is a dupe, at least not that one. The OP is asking for a way to sort by groups of `id`.

Comment: Why is `id - 110` first? what is the logic behind the sorting?

Comment: @Sotos Column `id` is not to be sorted, only `var1` is, within each group of `id`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Note.* As mentioned by Moody_Mudskipper, there is no need to use `tidyverse` and can also be done easily with base `R`:

```
df[order(ordered(df$id, unique(df$id)), df$var1), ]
```

---

A one-liner `tidyverse` solution w/o any `temp` vars:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% arrange(ordered(id, unique(id)), var1)
#    id var1 var2
# 1 110   26  234
# 2 110   21   12
# 3 110   54   43
# 4  90   10   32
# 5  90   18   21
# 6  90    9   19
# 7  90   16   16
# 8 252   54   34
# 9 252   39   44
```

---

**Explanation of why `apply(df, 2, sort)` does not work**

What you were trying to do is to sort each column independently. `apply` runs over the specified dimension (`2` in this case which corresponds to columns) and applies the function (`sort` in this case).

`apply` tries to further simplify the results, in this case to a matrix. So you are getting back a matrix (*not*  a `data.frame`) where each column is sorted independently. For example this row from the `apply` call:

```
# [1,]  90    9   12
```

does not even exist in the original `data.frame`.

Comment: In base `R` your solution would become `df[order(factor(df$id,unique(df$id)), df$var1),]` (I use `factor` instead of `ordered` as `ordered` is not necessary, longer to type and less known).

Comment: True, `ordered` is longer than `factor` but IMHO semantically clearer.  A `factor` has only an implicit `order` while `ordered` has an explicit one. `R` is not coherent here I would say: `min(factor(1:3, 3:1))` does not work for obvious reasons, but  `sort( factor(1:3, 3:1))`  does, because the `factor` is silently treated as a numeric.

Comment: In my view `ordered` is something I would use for models, to aggregate values (`range`,`min`, `max`, `median`, `quantile`, ...), or  to arrange ggplot categories, so I see its use here as extra complexity, but I see your point (relevant: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396591/factors-ordered-vs-levels/45196908#45196908 ). But I'm nitpicking (and upvoted from the start).

Comment: Good read +1. I think that `sort(factor(.))` works because of legacy reasons rather than intentional. I can hardly imagine how you would define a sort algorithm w/o comparison ops. At some point it was too late to fix that and now it is valid R code. My take is that I want to be explicit rather than implicit to make my code more understandable. That's why tidyverse` wins for me over `data.table`, unless performance is a deakbreaker.

Answer (score 6):

Another base R option using `order` and `match`

```
df[with(df, order(match(id, unique(id)), var1, var2)), ]
#   id var1 var2
#2 110   21   12
#1 110   26  234
#3 110   54   43
#6  90    9   19
#4  90   10   32
#7  90   16   16
#5  90   18   21
#9 252   39   44
#8 252   54   34
```

Answer (score 3):

We can convert the `id` to factor in order to split while preserving the original order. We can then loop over the list and order, and `rbind` again, i.e.

```
df$id <- factor(df$id, levels = unique(df$id))
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), function(i)i[order(i$var1),]))

#       id var1 var2
#110.2 110   21   12
#110.1 110   26  234
#110.3 110   54   43
#90.6   90    9   19
#90.4   90   10   32
#90.7   90   16   16
#90.5   90   18   21
#252.9 252   39   44
#252.8 252   54   34
```

**NOTE:** You can reset the rownames by `rownames(new_df) <- NULL`

Answer (score 3):

In base `R` we could use `split<-` :

```
split(df,df$id) <- lapply(split(df,df$id), function(x) x[order(x$var1),] )
```

or as @Markus suggests :

```
split(df, df$id) <- by(df, df$id, function(x) x[order(x$var1),])
```

output in either case :

```
df
#    id var1 var2
# 1 110   21   12
# 2 110   26  234
# 3 110   54   43
# 4  90    9   19
# 5  90   10   32
# 6  90   16   16
# 7  90   18   21
# 8 252   39   44
# 9 252   54   34
```

Answer (score 2):

With the following `tidyverse` pipe, the question's output is reproduced.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(tmp = cumsum(c(0, diff(id) != 0))) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(tmp, var1) %>%
  select(-tmp)
## A tibble: 9 x 3
## Groups:   id [3]
#     id  var1  var2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   110    21    12
#2   110    26   234
#3   110    54    43
#4    90     9    19
#5    90    10    32
#6    90    16    16
#7    90    18    21
#8   252    39    44
#9   252    54    34
```