# How to compare factor levels with different order?

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(
    cola = c('a','b','c','d','e','e','1',NA,'c','d'),
    colb = c("A",NA,"C","D",'a','b','c','d','c','d'),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#equal 2 dataframe
df2<-df

df['cola'] <- lapply(df['cola'], function(x) droplevels(factor(x,levels=c('a','b','c','d','e','f','1'),ordered = FALSE)))

df2['cola'] <- lapply(df2['cola'], function(x) factor(x,ordered = FALSE))

#should be eqaul
dplyr::all_equal(df,df2)

#check levels
levels(df$cola)
levels(df2$cola)
```

Output of above script is:

```
> dplyr::all_equal(df,df2)
[1] "Factor levels not equal for column `cola`"

> levels(df$cola)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "1"

> levels(df2$cola)
[1] "1" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

As for **`ordered = FALSE`**,`"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "1"`  should be equal to `"1" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"`
Why `all_equal` tell me `Factor levels not equal`?

How to compare these 2 factor level to be equal?

Comment: can I mark as duplicate of this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396591

Comment: I don't think so,because I cannot find answer from that post.

Comment: The `convert = TRUE` argument in `all_equal` might be helpful.

Comment: @mt1022,`convert = TRUE` give `TRUE` result,but miss `levels` comparision

Comment: The linked post shows you how the order of levels in an unordered factor still matters in some circumstances. try `as.numeric(df$cola);as.numeric(df2$cola)` or `sort(df$cola);sort(df2$cola)`. `all.equal` and `all_equal` make some choices as to what they're checking and they check this by default. and I think your last question is answered by @jay.sf

Comment: I think we should discriminate between "represented equally" and "logically equal". First, `df$cola` and `df2$cola` are unequal because their levels are different and represented differently in R. Second, they are not `ordered` so that they are logically equal in regression (excpet for which value will be chosen as base).

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper,which means `ordered = FALSE` not really ignore levels order?And no one existing function can be used to compare factors with `real ignore levels order`?

Comment: levels have an order, because `levels` is an attribute of the factor object , this attribute is a character vector, and a character vector contains elements in a given order. Ignoring level order or not is a choice that belongs to the function that you apply on your factor object. It appears `all_equal` cares by default while @jay.sf's function doesn't.

Comment: `ordered` is a way to mark the variable as ordinal rather than categorical, it  basically means you can use `min`, `max`, `quantiles`... and that some models will take the fact they are ordered into account. You can still sort unordered factors however and the order of their levels will still sometimes have an impact, on the display of ggplot charts for example.

Answer (score 2):

The reason becomes clearer if you use the original `all.equal`.

```
all.equal(df, df2)
# [1] "Component “cola”: Attributes: < Component “levels”: 6 string mismatches >"
```

Your levels just don't match each other. This is concise with compairing columns of a data.frame or two string vectors:

```
all.equal(letters[c(3, 1, 2)], letters[c(2, 3, 1)])
# [1] "3 string mismatches"
```

You could use `sort` instead.

```
sort(levels(df$cola)) == sort(levels(df2$cola))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

To check all, use `all`.

```
all(sort(levels(df$cola)) == sort(levels(df2$cola)))
# [1] TRUE
```

You could wrap it into a function.

```
checkEqualLevels <- function(l, x, y) {
  if (all(sort(levels(x[[l]])) == sort(levels(y[[l]]))))
    cat(paste0("Factor levels are equal for column ", "'", l, "'"))
  else
    cat(paste0("Factor levels not equal for column ", "'", l, "'"))
}
checkEqualLevels("cola", df, df2)
# Factor levels are equal for column 'cola'
```

Comment: Yes,but we still don't know the reason.

Comment: The truth:levels order still be compared even factor is `ordered = FALSE`.Totally  against  common sense.