# Maintain order of elements in dataframe filter and pipe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

In a nutshell, I want to maintain the order of elements in a dataframe after I apply a boolean operator and some filters, but my code is reordering the elements in alphabetical order.
In an investment model I'm working on I have a dataframe of symbols (as characters) as such:

```
library(tidyverse)

t <- data.frame(c("MO", "ABT", "PFE"))
names(t) <- c("symbol")
```

I have a large dataframe full of end-of-month prices (which is too large to replicate here), so assume that this dataframe is called "allprices" and it contains the prices for the symbols "MO", "ABT", and "PFE".  The "allprices" dataframe has a column called 'date'.

Then I have some date values used for filtering.

```
month1 <- date("2005-11-30")
month2 <- date("2005-12-31")
```

Now I run my code to subset the "allprices" dataframe that contains the symbols and is in between the specific dates.  The problem is this orders the data in alphabetical order by symbol....which I do not want to happen.

```
  Prices1 <- allprices %>% 
    filter(symbol %in% as.character(t$symbol)) %>% 
    filter(date >= month1 & date <= month2)
```

My desired result is a dataframe with prices for month1 and month2 for "MO", "ABT", and "PFE" in this order.  In the above code the resulting order is "ABT", "MO", "PFE", which is again, not what I want.

Is there a way to arrange Prices1 to match that of t?  Perhaps arrange and match in a pipe after the filters???

Comment: You can use an `ordered` `factor` to allow R's sort functions to work properly. It will also allow you to use functions like `max` and `min` to extract last/first values by order. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396591/factors-ordered-vs-levels

Answer (score 0):

You can `arrange` the data :

```
library(dplyr)

Prices1 <- allprices %>% 
            filter(symbol %in% as.character(t$symbol)) %>% 
            filter(date >= month1 & date <= month2) %>%
            arrange(match(symbol, as.character(t$symbol)))
```

Comment: This works great.  Thanks!  Also, my next step is to convert this to a zoo series in order to calculate returns for each symbol.  My code for this is: Prices_zoo <- do.call(merge, by(Prices1, Prices1$symbol, function(x) zoo(x$price, x$date))).  My new problem is this zoo series is also out of order.  Will the same idea with using arrange and match work in the zoo series?  I thought that once I got the order in Prices1 correct it would carry through.  But it does not.

Comment: `merge` will not necessarily maintain the order. I am not sure if you can use `arrange` on `zoo` series but the same logic can be applied with `match`. Something like `Prices_zoo[match(symbol, as.character(t$symbol)), ]`. You may need to change `symbol` to accurately refer to values from `Prices_zoo`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```r
library(tidyverse)

t %>% left_join(allprices)
```

instead of the equivalent steps above